# What limits does an API endpoint impose on transactions which fail due to assertions?

Tags: transactions, api, balances

Scenario: I connect to an API endpoint and repeatedly send transactions (with `cleos`) which are all ultimately rejected with `eosio_assert_message`.
Such transactions don't seem to eat up CPU or network resources of my account.
Still, the API endpoint has to actually execute the code to get to the assertion, so it consumes at least the CPU of the endpoint.

In practice, after a few such API calls, I'm getting the "overdrawn balance" response, as if my CPU or network resource was spent.
But it persists only for a few seconds.
And no spendings are reflected on my account details.

So, what is the mechanism for the API endpoint to limit the transactions which actually don't make it because of failed assertions?

Comment: Yes it has an impact on a single node, but it can't broadcast to other nodes, however, you can send txs to all nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the responses in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/5116), the mechanisms that are meant to mitigate this issue are as follows:

> - There's a maximum cpu time(30ms) for every transaction.
> - If a transaction failed, it will not be broadcast to other nodes, which means that hackers can only exhausts one see node rather than
>     the whole network.
> - greylist feature further prevents from hackers stealing elastic CPU/NET resources.

To read more about greylisting, see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/4368) for a technical explanation or [this article](https://steemit.com/eos/@greymass/greylisting-on-eos) for a less technical explanation. Briefly, accounts that are subjectively considered to spam the network are restricted from using the *unused* bandwidth that accounts are entitled to otherwise.

Overall, it seems that there is no protocol-level defense that stops an attacker from incessantly broadcasting 30ms failing transactions to BPs at no costs (beside electricity) to waste BP resources.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! In my experience though, there seemed to be some mechanism other than greylisting in play. After ~10 calls in a few seconds, the API endpoint said that I have "overdrawn balance", as if it speculatively counted my actions towards CPU limit or anything. After waiting for a minute, the error vanished though. Isn't greylisting more manual and more permanent?